# Is that possible to create an atomic local variable without using a property?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, atomic

I am inside a method with a code like this

```
  __block NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

  [anotherArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                            usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

     // do some calculation and generate an object
     [myArray addObject:anObject];


  }];
```

because the enumeration is concurrent, I have a crash when several threads try to add objects to myArray.

I know about atomic properties but I wonder if there is a way of making myArray atomic and thread safe without using a property. I want to keep it local.

Comment: If you need thread safe updates to `myArray`, then why use a concurrent enumeration?

Comment: because it is faster?

Comment: atomic properties won't help at all. access the property is safe but the object inside the property still not thread-safe

Comment: @BryanChen - why is that?

Comment: The gain will likely be lost by needing serial access to `myArray`

Comment: @maddy - not really. By some strange issue, this method runs perfectly depending on some other conditions when it is called and it is pretty fast compared to a non-concurrent version of it. This is probably because some calculation is done before the object is added and that calculation is done in multiple threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

old C array may help

```
id array[anotherArray.count];
id __strong *arrayPtr = array;

  [anotherArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                            usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

     // do some calculation and generate an object
     arrayPtr[idx] = anObject;

  }];

 NSMutableArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:array count:anotherArray.count];
```

Comment: @rmaddy I know. But so? `array[idx]` is different memory location for every thread. no two thread going to access same address at same time. It won't be safe if `array` is `NSArray`, but it is fine for `id[]`

Comment: the first line gives me an error "variable-sized object may not be initialized"...

Comment: Oops - I misread your code. You are using a C array. I misread it as another NSArray. This is actually a good solution. Sorry.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this approach only works if the resulting array should have a one-to-one result from the original array.

Comment: @BryanChen - that works on the initialization but will fail on the line `array[idx] = anObject;` with the error "cannot refer to declaration with a variably modified type inside a block"

Comment: @RubberDuck try add `__block`

Comment: "block attribute not allowed on declaration with a variably modified type" error on the declaration. Now the error on the second line vanished.

Comment: @RubberDuck looks like block doesn't like array... try updated code

Comment: @BryanChen - error on `id *arrayPtr = array;`... pointer to non-const type id with no explicit ownership... :)

Answer (score 3):

Since you need serial access to `myArray`, using a concurrent enumeration may be pointless. But it may depend on what you do in the enumeration besides adding the object to the array.

You can synchronize access to the array:

```
@synchronized(myArray) {
    [myArray addObject:anObject];
}
```

It would be interesting to run some performance tests to see if doing the above is actually slower than simply using a serial enumeration since you then wouldn't need the overhead of synchronizing the array.